# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer (error in while condition)

Tags: c, pointers

i have unknown error in my code after i test my code by printing i know that function that cause the error :

```
void clearTrainSet(){

        struct trainSet * curSet=trnHead;
        struct trainSet * tmp;
puts("z");
        while(curSet!=NULL){
puts("0");
                tmp=curSet;
puts("1");
                curSet=curSet->next;
puts("2");
                free(tmp->input);
puts("3");
                free(tmp->output);
puts("4");
                free(tmp);
puts("x");
        }
        trnHead=NULL;
        if(filename!=NULL){
                free(filename);
                filename=NULL;
        }
puts("c");
}
```

after testing the program the result is:

```
./neuromz -new 1 2 3 -name dsd
Network initialized successfully.
z
*** Error in `./neuromz': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffde363d2c0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

so the error in while's condition

Comment: How did you initialize `filename`? Has the value you are passing to `free` been handed back by `calloc`, `malloc` or `realloc`?

Comment: thank you finally i fix my code , that problem was i use filename by two ways inside the program `malloc` by argument `filename=argv[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your comment, it is evident that you were passing such a pointer to `free` which was not returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. This invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (in fact, IMO, you were quite lucky to get a segmentation fault. It could have been [worse](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)). This is what the man page says about `void free(void *ptr);`:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr which must
>   have been returned by a previous call to  malloc(),  calloc() or 
>   realloc().  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before,
>   undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.